# FileNotFoundException even if it exists in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-filesystem

In laravel, I am making an application that uploads a file and the user can retrieve that same file.

But each time I click to upload I get this error.

```
FileNotFoundException in FilesystemAdapter.php line 91:
/storage/ap/payments/98AcresResort_25.pdf
```

my controller code is this:

```
$filePath = "/storage/ap/payments/".$payment->payment_image;
$file = storage::disk('public')->get($filePath);
```

my file is located at `/public/storage/ap/payments/filename.pdf`

I tried `php artisan storage:link`

Can anyone suggest any solution, please?

Comment: have you ran this command `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: May be because of cache ?

Comment: by default `storage::disk('public')` will prepend the path with `/your/path/to/project/storage/app/public/`

Comment: Yeah I tried `php artisan storage:link`.

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo cause you have `/storage/ap/` but the default would be `/storage/app/`.

Comment: Your file is located under the `/your-app/public/storage` folder, not `/your-app/storage/app/public/storage` folder. Is that that right?

Comment: @cbaconnier Yeah

Comment: If you didn't change the default storage disk then it's not going to upload it to that specific disk by default. 

So you could try to just use Storage::get($filePath);
This is all specified in config/filesystems.php

Storage::disk('public') is not a method to select the public folder.
It's a method to select the 'public' disk. The path is a bit different

So if you didn't specify that your app uses public by default it will probably be on the 'local' disk.

EDIT: @cbaconnier his answer details on how to add a disk with your specific file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your file is located at this place `/your-app/public/storage/ap/payments/filename.pdf` you need to add a disk.

In the file `config/filesystems.php`

add the disk

```
'disks' => [

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
    ],
```

Then you can use it like this

```
$filePath = "storage/ap/payments/".$payment->payment_image;
$file = Storage::disk('web')->get($filePath);
```

It will look for the location

`/your-app/public/storage/ap/payments/filename.pdf"`

But I suspect that your file `/public/storage/ap/payments/filename.pdf` was also in the `/storage` folder and that you're working through a symlink. The correct ways would be to have **app** instead of **ap** and to use the `public` disk like this `Storage::disk('public')->path('payments/filename.pdf')`

Even better, since it's a a payment, you probably don't want the file to be **public** and accessible to all. In that case you can use the disk `local` and serve the file on request. But that's maybe more advanced stuff.

Comment: I have tried this. I added the disk and tried this code. still, doesn't work. Now I get an error that `InvalidArgumentException in FilesystemManager.php line 121:
Driver [] is not supported.`.

Comment: @suganthansivananthan your file do looks like this: https://pastebin.com/DPijxM2G right? Then, maybe try `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

Please run below command for create storage folder in public foler:

```
php artisan storage:link


$filePath = public_path("storage/ap/payments/".$payment->payment_image);
```